# MyPy Errors for Decorator w/ Arguments

Tags: python, python-decorators, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I'm trying to do strict type checking with MyPy and I can't seem to get decorators with arguments to work without throwing conflicting errors.

According to docs and other answers, I think you should have something like this:

```
from time import sleep 
from typing import TypeVar, Any, Callable, cast

F = TypeVar('F', bound=Callable[..., Any])

def multi_try_if_error(n_tries: int, sleep_duration: int) -> F:
    def decorator(fn: F) -> F:
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            for _ in range(n_tries):
                try:
                    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
                except Exception as e:
                    caught = e
                    sleep(sleep_duration)
            raise ValueError(caught)
        return cast(F, wrapper)
    return cast(F, decorator)


# example usage — this is where the error is raised
@multi_try_if_error(n_tries=3, sleep_duration=1)
def query_db(q: str) -> None:
    return
```

But this gives the following errors:

```
lib/decorator_defined.py:32: error: Function is missing a type annotation
lib/decorator_used.py:23: error: Untyped decorator makes function "query_db" untyped
lib/decorator_used.py:23: error: <nothing> not callable
```

Even though it's not what the docs suggest, I can change the wrapper definition to:

```
def wrapper(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
    for _ in range(n_tries):
        ...
```

Which resolves the first error, but I still have the other two decorator errors wherever the decorator is used.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

The error can be reproduced on Mypy playground [here](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=show-error-codes%2Cstrict&gist=f57228d1972359358072fbb21be79b03).

Comment: @AlexWaygood Thanks for the response! So it's actually not a problem with the decorator definition, but when the decorator is used with the definition of another function. I've edited my question to show this (which is reproducible in the playground).

Comment: @AlexWaygood The `ReadDataError` is just a `ValueError` and can be substituted accordingly with no difference. I also edited the question to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is the return type of the outer layer of your decorator. You need to correct your type annotation to the following:

```
from time import sleep 
from typing import TypeVar, Any, Callable, cast

F = TypeVar('F', bound=Callable[..., Any])

def multi_try_if_error(n_tries: int, sleep_duration: int) -> Callable[[F], F]:
    def decorator(fn: F) -> F:
        def wrapper(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
            for _ in range(n_tries):
                try:
                    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
                except Exception as e:
                    caught = e
                    sleep(sleep_duration)
            raise ValueError(caught)
        return cast(F, wrapper)
    return decorator


@multi_try_if_error(n_tries=3, sleep_duration=1)
def query_db(q: str) -> None:
    return
```

##### What's going on here

Conceptualising (and type-hinting) a simple decorator that doesn't take arguments is fairly straighforward. We define a function `C` that takes in a function of type `F` and spits out a new function that is also of type `F`.

```
# Decorator that doesn't take arguments takes in a function,
# and spits out a function of the same type
DecoratorTypeNoArgs = Callable[[F], F]
```

It's important to recognise, however, that that's *not* what a decorator that takes arguments is doing. Rather than taking in a function of type `F` and spitting out a new function of type `F` (which can be conceptualised as `Callable[[F], F]`), `multi_try_if_error` is a function that takes in two `int` arguments and *returns* a function that will take in a function of type `F` and return a function of type `F` (which can be conceptualised as `Callable[[int, int], Callable[[F], F]]`).

```
# Decorator that takes arguments takes in arguments,
# and spits out a decorator that doesn't take arguments
DecoratorTypeWithArgs = Callable[[int, int], Callable[[F], F]]
```

As such, the outer layer of your decorator must be annotated as returning `Callable[[F], F]` rather than as returning `F`. Once you make this change, your decorator [passes MyPy --strict](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=059deff5e9f5b6721c94c10e8157963d) with flying colours.

Answer (score 0):

For people using Python >= 3.10 [Alex' great solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69030553/3876599) can be written a bit more succinct with the help of the new [parameter specification variables](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-612-parameter-specification-variables).

Quoting the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec), this can us help us with the following problems of the "legacy" solution:

> 1. The type checker can’t type check the inner function because `*args` and `**kwargs` have to be typed `Any`.
> 2. `cast()` may be required in the body of the add_logging decorator when returning the inner function, or the static type checker must be told to ignore the `return inner`.

```py
from time import sleep
from typing import Callable, ParamSpec, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")
P = ParamSpec("P")


def multi_try_if_error(
    n_tries: int, sleep_duration: int
) -> Callable[[Callable[P, T]], Callable[P, T]]:
    def decorator(fn: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[P, T]:
        def wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
            for _ in range(n_tries):
                try:
                    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
                except Exception as e:
                    caught = e
                    sleep(sleep_duration)

            raise ValueError(caught)

        return wrapper

    return decorator
```